# SQL developer popup JPDA - how to turn off?

Tags: debugging, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsql-package, jpda

I have a package that I need to debug, when I compile and hit debug in SQL Developer, popup appears: "Listen for JPDA" and I cannot enter into debug, breakpoint is set and "Step Into" is also checked in Preferences.
I tried setting up preferences to use DBMS_DEBUGGER no luck, tried to edit sqldeveloper.config file, no luck. Any idea how to turn popup off?

[[Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i8JX.png)]

[popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGMS2.png)

I tried setting preferences to use DBMS_DEBUGGER.
Try to edit sqldeveloper.config
tried restarting SQL Developer
There is no Listener running in processes when i hit cancel on JPDA it starts Listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all of settings in C:\Users<name of user>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer and it stopped. But really it is not a good solution if you have xy databases, you should export all connections first